# How to change WCF Binding and Endpoint properties using AutofacServiceHostFactory

Tags: autofac, wcf

I would like to increase the MaxBufferSize, MaxBufferPoolSize, ReceivedMessageSize, along with the readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646", It is my understanding that I must change these parameters in the registration process.  But I see no examples anywhere on doing this.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found an answer to this or not but it would look something like this:

```
builder.Register(
    container =>
        new ChannelFactory<TService>(
            new WSHttpBinding { TransactionFlow = supportTransactionFlow, 
                                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483646, 
                                ReaderQuotas = { 
                                      MaxStringContentLength = 2147483646,
                                      MaxDepth = 2147483646,
                                      MaxArrayLength= 2147483646 }},
            endpointAddress)).InstancePerDependency();
```